# How to Bind JQueryDataTable on Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I want to bind another JQueryDataTable on  one JQueryDataTable's column click on the same page with Ajax.Here is my code of Both JQueryDataTables.
and at start i want 2nd table to display "No Data" untill first table's column click.Please guide me
[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        function DrawTable() {
            var props = null;
            BindDataTable({ AllowPaging: true, ShowFilter: false, ShowEditLink: true, EmptyTableText: 'No Data Found', SortIndex: 0, SortDirection: "asc" },
                              "#tblQueues",
                              "@Url.Action("GetAllQueues", "Queue")",
                              props,
                              [{ name: "Id", cellClass: "alignCenter", Sortable: true, index: 0 }, { }],
                              [{ name: "Id", type: "anchor", title: 'queueTable', DisplayPropName: 'Name', viewtitle: 'View', link: '@Url.Action("QueueTickets", "Queue")', index: 0 }]);
        }

        DrawTable();

    });





</script>
```

Comment: @Guruparasad Rao can u help me in this issue

Comment: What isn't working about the code you've tried so far? Please try and be specific.

Comment: @AlexLynham both are working but i want that 2nd table should not show anythimg untill i click on first tables column...read description first

Comment: There are a lot of things that could be causing this, but we can't tell without knowing a lot more. What's you HTML look like? Where's the data come from and what does it look like? With the code you have above, I can't see how you'd initiate a second table.

Comment: @jonmrich  data will come from db on the base of selected Queue's Id and  on the base of that 2nd table will be binded

Comment: How is the JSON for the second table generated (where's the code)? How is the second table drawn (HTML and js/jquery)? The code you have now is not complete enough to give an answer